# SQL select duplicate rows based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a request that returns me IDs of rows having the same column value. For example :

```
id    | Value
______________
1     | label1
2     | label1
3     | label1
4     | label2
5     | label2
```

I'd like to get this kind of result :

```
id    | AlternateID   | Value
______________________________
1     | 2             | label1
1     | 3             | label1
4     | 5             | label2
```

The best result I got so far is :

```
id    | AlternateID   | Value
______________________________
1     | 2             | label1
2     | 1             | label1
1     | 3             | label1
3     | 1             | label1
4     | 5             | label2
5     | 4             | label2
```

But as you can see, I have duplicate values across the first two columns

...Right now, without using cursors, I'm stuck.

I am on SQL Server 2008.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the numbers?  It is not obvious to me.

Comment: We can not tell what you are really looking for here. Are you wanting to group by and get a count?

Comment: the first table numbers correspond to the id of the row.
the second table is like a Map. For example, ID 1 can be used instead ID 2 and ID 3 / ID 4 can ben used instead of ID5

I guess there is something around a group by clause... but I am really stuck ...

Comment: Please update your question or add some code how you got to the first table. It's a little hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I interpret the question as getting pairs of id's that are related through the `value` column.  That is the only way I can make sense of the numbers being produced.

Comment: You may want to change the name of the column "Value" in your desired result.  I think it's throwing some people (including me) off.  Maybe update it to "AlternateID" or something along those lines?  Might help reduce some confusion.

Comment: I've updated my answer thanks to your comments, hope it makes more sense for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a derived table to get your base values and join it back to the original table.

```
SELECT 
  a.id,
  b.id as AlternateID,
  a.value
FROM 
  (SELECT MIN(id) as id , value FROM YourTable GROUP BY value) a
JOIN YourTable b on a.value = b.value and a.id <> b.id
```

Comment: This was the solution ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want pairs of ids with the same value.

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2, t1.value
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.id < t2.id and t1.value = t2.value;
```

Comment: The issue of the solution is that I get this
`1 | 2 | label1 ` //
`2 | 1 | label1` ....
I got also this result with a join :/

Comment: @r4phG . . . Not at all.  The `t1.id < t2.id` prevents two such rows from being generated.

Comment: You are right, I've used `t1.id <> t2.id` which caused the issue. Sorry and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Get the min row first then outer join or outer apply to alternate values

```
SELECT  mt.id, mt2.AlternateID, mt.Value
FROM    ( SELECT *, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY VALUE ORDER BY id ) Rn
            FROM myTable
        ) mt
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT id [AlternateID]   -- use CROSS APPLY to only return dupes
                     FROM   myTable mt2
                     WHERE  mt2.VALUE = mt.VALUE AND mt2.id <> mt.id) mt2
WHERE   Rn = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe this could work, but I couldn't get this query working :/

Comment: did you try using your actual table name?

Comment: ^^. Of course ! I have a problem around the OVER( PARTITION ...) Rn

Comment: lol  you might be on older version of sql server or the compatibility mode is still set to 2005.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e400d/1